# Executable running in background

Tags: vbscript, jenkins, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run a simple batch script via Jenkins (which in turn calls a VBscript). The script which i am executing in Jenkins is:

```
cd "C:\Product\workspace"
cscript Test.vbs
```

The test.vbs is simple code which calls an exe in console mode

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /K C:\Product\workspace\Product.exe -c -dir C:\ProductDir", 1
Set objShell = Nothing
```

> *The parameter 1 : Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position.*

The problem which I am facing is I am not able to see the cmd.exe and the Product.exe installer. Though the process explorer shows cmd.exe and Product.exe running. I don't get why I its not running in foreground and only in background.

1. How can I get the exe to run in foreground?
2. When I tried running directly on VM, I can see it running in foreground. Cant understand this situation. Any light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The command launches the `CMD` window in the foreground for me (I'm not running it in Jenkins, though). Perhaps you can set the window title `objShell.Run "cmd /k title xyz & Product.exe ...", 1` and then bring it to the foreground via `objShell.AppActivate "xyz"`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Ya same happens with me when i don't use Jenkins, it works properly but with Jenkins the problem appears. And also I tried ur suggestion...no help...

Comment: Then the problem is with Jenkins. Sorry, can't help you there.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: No problem..U have helped me a lot. Thanks for ur effor :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Jenkins slave agent as headless service on windows? I remember in this case the GUI would have problem. You should run the agent with jnlp when you add the slave VM. This works perfect with me.

Comment: Agent is running with jnlp only.

Comment: My experience is use WScript.Shell.Exec with GUI application. Take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/507798/Differences-between-Run-and-Exec-VBScript

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to skin the cat using VBScript.

I experienced the same issue trying schedule a task to launch Internet Explorer into the foreground. I was using WScript's `Run` method with the `3` window option to force it to be maximized. I just couldn't force it to come up in the foreground.

I FINALLY got that to work with WScript's `AppActivate` method.  The trick was to monitor `AppActivate`'s return value in a loop to ensure the application is fully launched with the correct TITLE before using `AppActivate` to bring it to the foreground.

[AppActivate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

## Here's my example script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "iexplore.exe https://www.google.com", 3, false
WScript.Sleep 2000
While WshShell.AppActivate("Internet Explorer") = FALSE
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Wend
WshShell.AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
WScript.Quit
```

=========================

Note: `AppActivate` will choose the closest match for the application TITLE (or process ID, which is not as simple). You don't have to have the complete TITLE. I'm showing "Internet Explorer" here, but I was able to use the TITLE of the web site that I was redirecting to ("Google" would work OK in this example).  So, if you don't want to pull up any random instance of an application you may already have open, be as specific as possible.  A `CMD.EXE` TITLE wouldn't be your best bet.

`AppActivate` works especially well for CMD/COMMAND windows, as (mentioned previously) you can use the TITLE batch file command to specify a unique window title.

Answer (score 0):

I think im late but I did this and it worked:

```vb
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /K C:\Product\workspace\Product.exe -c -dir C:\ProductDir", 0, False Rem 0: run in background, False: exit without waiting process to stop, True to wait for process
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .visible property in order to display the applications that are running and bring them to the foreground e.g. objShell.Visible = True

Example below of how I used it when launching an application:

```
Dim objQtpApp 

Set objQtpApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")

'make QTP visible
objQtpApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: [`WshShell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) objects don't have a `Visible` property.